# Prestashop modules translations save to a white page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hello i am new to prestashop so excuse me for this issue might be common i am not sure i have prestashop version 1.6 and now i am translating modules and when i save i get redirected to a blank page but my newly translations are saved i don't understand why this is happening although it didn't happen while i was translating the Frontoffice translations.I think maybe because of the long list of modules which result **4505** translations.I have a godaddy economy hosting package and here is my custom **php.ini**

```
max_input_vars = 5000
post_max_size = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 256M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work as memory_limit is set to 128M. You can this check the below links.

[LINK 1](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/blank-screen)

[LINK 2](http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/prestashop-16-tutorials/fix-blank-white-screen-prestashop16)

[LINK 3](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/prestashop-how-to-fix-the-blank-product-page-issue.html)

If this doesn't work, try `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Comment: I made memory_limit = 512M in php.ini and also ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); in config/config.inc.php and define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true); in config/defines.inc.php but nothing changed still i get submitted to white page but my translations are saved

Comment: After setting memory_limit = 512M in php.ini have you restarted the server ? Or try clearing cache

Comment: I just tried somethin .. the translation form submit to AdminTranslationsController so i added @ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
 @error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); at the beginning of the file and then i found this error


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/username/public_html/modules/spblocknewsletter/translations/ar.php:1) in /home/username/public_html/classes/Tools.php on line 252

Do you got any ideas what should i do from this point ?

Comment: There may be a space before php tag in the file ar.php(/modules/spblocknewsletter/transla‌​tions/ar.php). Check please

Comment: @YasserMoussa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php